# Exception thrown in upgrading from SP 2013 RTM to SP 2013 Service Pack1

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, upgrade, service-pack

[image: error-inupgrade-to-sp2013-sp1]

i am trying to upgrade my sp 2013 RTM to 2013 SP1, but i am getting the error as shown in screen shot.
how to resolve this error.

error description:

> 01/25/2017 10:59:44  13  WRN                  Failed to add the service connection point for this farm
>   01/25/2017 10:59:44  13  INF                  Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
>   01/25/2017 10:59:44  13  INF                    Resource id to be retrieved is ServiceConnectionPointNotCreatedEventLog for language English (United States)
>   01/25/2017 10:59:44  13  INF                    Resource retrieved id ServiceConnectionPointNotCreatedEventLog is Unable to create a Service Connection Point in the current Active Directory domain. Verify that the SharePoint container exists in the current domain and that you have rights to write to it.
>   01/25/2017 10:59:44  13  INF                  Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
>   01/25/2017 10:59:44  13  WRN                  Unable to create a Service Connection Point in the current Active Directory domain. Verify that the SharePoint container exists in the current domain and that you have rights to write to it.
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The object LDAP://CN=Microsoft SharePoint Products,CN=System,DC=ad,DC=mycompanydomain,DC=com doesn't exist in the directory.
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServiceConnectionPoint.Ensure(String serviceBindingInformation)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.UpgradeTask.Run()
>   01/25/2017 10:59:44  1  INF                  Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
>   01/25/2017 10:59:44  1  INF
>
> aj0ur  ERROR   Upgrade Timer job is exiting due to exception: 
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException: Upgrade completed with errors. 
>    Review the upgrade log file located in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS\Upgrade-20170125-105656-834.log. 
>    The number of errors and warnings is listed at the end of the upgrade log file.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.CheckPoint() 
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.LogEnd()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUpgradeJobDefinition.Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)
>       8964ce9d-77b4-f0ef-e280-071cfece4693

Comment: Check this link -  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30998.sharepoint-products-configuration-wizard-failed.aspx

Comment: my issue is Unable to create a Service Connection Point in the current Active Directory domain. Verify that the SharePoint container exists in the current domain and that you have rights to write to it. Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The object LDAP://CN=Microsoft SharePoint Products,CN=System,DC=ad,DC=mycompanydomain,DC=com doesn't exist in the directory. at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServiceConnectionPoint.Ensure(String serviceBindingInformation) at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.UpgradeTask.Run() 01/25/2017 10:59:44 1 INF Not running in high contrast,

Comment: so, how to resolve this service connection point issue

Comment: go to `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS` folder, here you will find the upgrade*-error.log file. Exact error is present there.